# Why is there a small pixel gap between tiles in CSS grid when gap is set to 0 (responsive map)?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-grid, sprite-sheet

I am trying to create a game level select map where I need different sprites from a spritesheet placed on a very specific tile in a grid. I use CSS grid for this and place the tiles on the grid inline with `grid-row-start` and `grid-column-start`. Everything works as it should, except for one thing: the tiles have a *small* gap between them, but `gap`is set to 0 in the CSS. That small gap is enough to look really jarring ([screenshot of map with the gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnMUQ.png)).

**Because this is a mobile game, it is important that the grid is responsive and works on all device sizes.** I am therefore working in percentages, and `vw` in the CSS. I am thinking that the gaps might be caused by decimal rounding errors?

The parent div:

```
.tilemap {
    display: grid;
    height: 150vw; /* 15 rows, 10 columns */
    grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 1fr);    /* 15 rows */
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1fr); /* 10 columns */
    gap: 0;
    place-content: stretch end;
}
```

The grid is full width (100vw) and each tile is 10vw = 10 columns. The height of the tilemap is 150vw = 15 rows. Each tile is squared ([screnshot of CSS grid in devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipZpI.png)).

Common class for all tiles:

```
.tilemap div {
    max-width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    background-image: url("../images/responsive-spritesheet.png");
}
```

And each tile has a different background position. Included for completeness:

```
.tilemap div.road.vertical {
    background-position: 0 100%;
}
```

The problem is not the spritesheet image, because the gaps still appear when I comment this out and replace it with `background-color` instead ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIThN.png)).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hope you set `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` in you CSS?

Comment: Also, could you reproduce this in a codepen?

Comment: Have you checked if your tiles inherit any other style from somewhere else? The behavior is very strange. Maybe you can post a screenshot of the devtools so we can see the styles applied to the the tiles. I just tried a very similar example in a sandbox and it's working just fine.

Comment: @JayCodist, margin and padding set to 0 did not change anything. I will try to reproduce it.

Comment: You will spend 2 days on fixing it and probably won't fix it... better change the layout to flex or floating.

Comment: @Reductio Screenshot of devtools: https://imgur.com/a/WG9TVg8. It does not look like there is anything interfering.

Comment: It looks like just one of those rendering issues, Can you put up a working snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked forever ago, but I solved a similar issue of my own by dropping fr units, and using exact lengths for my grid cells.

This might help you, because I see you're using `repeat()` and thus have equal spacing in your grid, like I do.